# Traveling to Europe from banned countries on sweetheart exception

Tags: customs-and-immigration, tickets, covid-19, portugal, denmark

Europe is mostly locked out from the US due to COVID except for essential travel. Tourism obviously does not count, but some countries have made exceptions for visiting important family, fiance, or "sweetheart".

See [this article](https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/news/eu-countries-that-have-reopened-borders-for-unmarried-partners-separated-by-entry-ban/) and this [policy page from Denmark](https://coronasmitte.dk/en/entry-into-denmark/persons-resident-in-banned-countries).

Does anyone know where I can find out which countries will honor a *transfer* through their country? For example, I emailed Iceland and they said they would definitely allow me to travel Icelandair and transfer to Denmark through Reykjavík. I am specifically wondering about Portugal (TAP), as they have the cheapest flights. I emailed their immigration, and they sent me this long and very confusing response: [pastebin because it is so long](https://pastebin.com/uLu18kZb).

I would mainly like to hear from people who have traveled to Europe from banned countries already, and what their experience has been. There's almost nothing on the internet about this, so any information you can offer would be helpful.

Comment: The situation in Europe is changing/worsening daily. Even if you do get replies, their experience may not be relevant to the current status, or mean that making such a trip is advisable

Comment: That's a good point. I'll take whatever information I can get tho. And in terms of whether it's a good idea, Denmark is still doing better than the US, and I haven't seen my fiance since December '19. If I can see her for 90 days, I'd really like to.

Comment: I sympathise because I’m in a similar position. If you’re set on making the trip, my advice would be to pick the simplest, most direct route even if that’s more expensive, and to get tested before you leave.

Comment: That would be transfer through Keflavík (KEF), not through Reykjakík (RKV)?

Comment: Err, yes Keflavik, the big airport. I actually didn't know what exactly was the distinction until now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For what it's worth, I should mention that I *was* successful traveling to Denmark via TAP AirPortugal, through Lisbon. They didn't give me any additional fuss.

Notes:

- You MUST meet the requirements of your destination country, they checked all of that in the US.
- You MUST have a negative Covid test valid 72 hours prior to departure. Depending on Covid testing in your area, this may be difficult. Plan ahead. Note that they DO accept "rapid" tests, which do not require a lab and return in about 15 minutes. However, rapid tests are less common than the more rigorous PCR tests, because they are less accurate.
- Portugal appears to be allowing significant transfer traffic. People on the same transatlantic flight as mine were connecting to cities all over Europe.
- All of this is probably subject to change at any time, especially with Vaccines, but a negative covid result less than 72 hours old will probably get you in about anywhere.